# Shorter method to solve $15a+16b+17c \le 272$ over non-negative integers

Tags: inequality

> How do I find number of non-negative integral solutions of this inequality?
> $$15a+16b+17c \le 272$$

Should I go by hit and trial, putting different values like $b=c=0$, etc, or is there a shorter method?

Comment: Note that $c \leq 16$.  For any given value of $c$, figure out how many possible solutions there are for $a, b$.  Then sum them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints: (If you're stuck, show what you've tried)

- Since $\frac{272}{15} = 18.13$, if $ a+b+c \geq 19$, then $ 15 a + 16 b + 17 c  > 15 \times 19 > 272$. Thus, there are no solutions with $ a + b + c \geq 19$.
- Since $ \frac{272}{17} = 16$, hence any solution to $ a + b + c \leq 16$ would also satisfy $15a + 16b + 17c \leq 17 (a+b+c) \leq 272$. There are ${19 \choose 3 } = 969$ solutions of this form.
- Any solutions to $ a + b + c = 17$ with $b+2c \leq 17$ are a solution. Conversely, if $ b+2c \leq 17$, we can set $ a = 17 - b - c$ to get a solution of this form. Hence, there are $18+16+\ldots +2 = 90$ solutions here.
- Any solutions to $a+b+c = 18$ with $ b + 2c \leq 2 $ are a solution. There are $3+1 = 4$ solutions here.

Thus, there are 1063 solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, Can you elaborate on the statement 272/15=18.13, so a+b+c≤18.?Why did you not solve this inequality to obtain 1330 as the number of  solutions?

Comment: Why is it not true that every solution of  a+b+c≤18 is a solution to my inequality?

Comment: @RishiShekher Is $ a=0, b=0, c = 18$ a solution to the inequality? IE Why did we need the condition that "If $ a+b+c = 18$, then $ b+2c \leq 2$? How did I arrive at this condition?

Comment: Thanks.I get it.